# Eclipse Android Webview, how to center the content

Tags: android, webview, center

I am nearly done with my first app, but I am still working on some little issues.

My main problem is that I am loading a normal html page, but I have no access to the html code.

Now I want to center the page in the webview module, because the page is also centered, so that when I am loading the page, I have to scroll all the time to the right side and that is really anoying.

So how do I do that, that the webview modul automatically loads the page already centered and the user of the app sees the middle of the page?

Answer (score 0):

You mean, you dont want horizontal scroll,for that try this :

```
mwebView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
```

Comment: and that i have to put in the java file, right? not in the xml file?

then i am importing layoutalgorithm but i am still getting the following message:
"mwebView cannot be resolved"

Comment: yes exaclty, replace mwebView with your webview object name, remember to tick the answer if it worked for you.

Comment: hm okay but now it is the problem that the page is user and password-safed, the users of the app have to enter the user and password to get access to the main page
it is a aspx page and when i am opening the page now, the app tries to open the password safed page, but it doesn't work and in the vertical center it stands, that the page is password safed and so on

because of that, i want to center the page also vertical

edit: and i am not able to enter username and password anymore :O

Comment: its hard to tell what are you trying to get, but i think you should try webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true)

Comment: instead of the upper code?

the point of the LayoutAlgorithm is that, it destroys the whole layout of the homepage/html code

well but i will try your second one, otherwise i will let it as it is already

Comment: well i doesnt work either way, but still thanks for your work ;)